# Azure Key Vault loses the name of my application within the Access policies

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, microsoft-entra-id

I use an **Azure Key Vault** to store secrets that I retrieve and use during the runtime of my DevOps Pipelines. My DevOps project used the Azure Subscription required for this, registered and authorized by Azure Resource Manager (Workload Identity Federation). After authorization, I can also easily view the secrets from the Azure Key Vault via the DevOps Library and use them from there. The connection is also displayed in Microsoft Entra ID as an application with a display name *My-application* and correct ID. The application is also visible in the Azure Key Vault with the *Get* and *List* authorizations in the section Access policies.

[image]

On the second run of my DevOps pipeline, the application name loses its validity. The application can no longer be resolved within the Access policies. In the Key Vault, the application is displayed as "unknown" and also with other rights that were automatically configured via Azure Resource Manager

**Error in my pipeline during pre-job download secrets:**

```
"The user, group or application 'appid=***;oid=ce890xxc-97xx-4703-bxx8-26exxa3c39xx;iss=https://sts.windows.net/<tenant>/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault
```

[image]

**Application is no longer recognized:**

[image]

If I update the Azure Resource Manager connection via DevOps Service Connections, this is corrected again and I can fix the error until the next run. The pipeline has remained unchanged for a long time. Why does Microsoft Entra ID lose the identity of this service connection after a single use?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are facing a transient issue, Make sure you do not change the service principal once its applied in the Access Policy of Key vault. And try to log into your Azure portal InPrivate tab to avoid cache related issue. You can also switch to RBAC based access control for key vault instead of Access policy and add your application Key vault administrator role to access key vault secrets:-

I created one Azure DevOps ARM service connection for one of the existing Azure AD Service principal and added it to the Access policy of Key vault:-

**My Service principal:-**

[image]

**Azure Devops Service Connection:-**

[image]

Added **powershell application** ***Get, List, permission in the Access Policy:-***

[image]

***Key vault secret:-***

[image]

**Task running first time:-**

***My Yaml pipeline:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'PowershellSid'
    KeyVaultName: 'siliconkeyvault84'
    SecretsFilter: '*'
    RunAsPreJob: false
```

[image]

**Access Policy:-**

[image]

**Second Run:-**

[image]

***The Application remained as it is and did not change to Unknown:-***

[image]

***Make sure your Application is registered and created properly in Azure AD.***